# WebSockets (server/client) implementation in J2SE --- why not?

Tags: java, sockets, websocket, server

Can we have an implementation of websockets in j2se?
I mean something similar to the old and not usable but lovely websocket4j?

I'm the author of an application server built in j2se. I don't care j2ee, I primarily use arrays, sockets, threads, db connectivity and filesystem access and it's all for my line. I just need to open to the websockets clientside world.
I don't need j2ee application servers. I don't want to use j2ee web containers. I need only to expand my application server build in plain java to be able to manage websocket sockets (http-handshaked sockets) as well as socket.

damn, somebody forgot the j2se implementation of the websockets?

I read it is not on plans (or only the clientside implementation), but I think what I'm asking should be already available; considered the coming importance of websockets. Isn't it? Why in J2EE only?

hope on some feedback.
thank you.

Comment: The application servers implementing web sockets are written in j2se, so yes.

Comment: Are you looking for something like this?  https://github.com/TooTallNate/Java-WebSocket

Comment: @Paul your answer is right. (thank you so much, it works as expected).

Comment: see also http://bayou.io/release/0.9/docs/ws/WebSocket_Server.html

Comment: .. but I have issues after recompiling the .jar file:
https://github.com/TooTallNate/Java-WebSocket/issues/328:
any suggest/advice?

(I'm patching the websockets's implementation simply to store the session_id of each connection in the respective WebSocket object to avoid using an hashmap to address the single sessions objects -- for example on each onMessage? needed for my software model)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

right answer came from @Paul:

> Are you looking for something like this? 
>   [github.com/TooTallNate/Java-WebSocket](http://github.com/TooTallNate/Java-WebSocket)

exactly.

Answer (score 0):

Your core question of "why" is probably a better fit for the [OpenSource SE](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/), but...

As an early adopter of Java, I'm sorry to say that there just isn't a whole lot of interest in J2SE anymore.  Some of my favorite J2SE libraries have been coasting on "good enough" since the Java 1.4 days, and libraries for newer technologies are hard to find, as you've discovered.

The good news is that it might not be too hard to write one.  There's a decent (can't say good because it's missing Javadoc) [Socket.IO client library for Android](https://github.com/nkzawa/socket.io-client.java) that would probably be easy to port to J2SE.  There are also a couple of server implementations floating around that I think have fallen behind in their support for current versions of Socket.IO.  You could bring one of those up to date and port it.  Maintain Android compatibility and it would probably attract a lot of support that would benefit both Android and J2SE.

Comment: I don't agree that "there just isn't a whole lot of interest in J2SE anymore."  One of the reasons behind [Java 8 Profiles](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/architect-profiles-2227131.html) is "Convergence of the Java ME Connected Device Configuration (CDC) with Java SE". As an Android developer you should be excited about what that will bring. The [java] tag has 896,307 questions, [java][android] has 119,932. There are a lot of SE users...as an enterprise developer I'm in the minority.

Answer (score 0):

## Atmosphere

You might find the [Atmosphere](https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere) ( the Asynchronous WebSocket/Comet Framework) open-source project interesting. See also the [Async-IO.org](http://async-io.org) site.

I believe this runs on Java SE, as I use it in [Vaadin](http://www.Vaadin.com/) web apps on Apache [Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org) on Java SE on Mac OS X.

## Servlet Containers

Apache Tomcat, Eclipse Jetty, and other open-source Servlet containers run on Java SE with WebSocket code you can use.

Java EE is basically Java SE plus a bunch of jars. You can pick and choose various libraries to run on Java SE.

Wikipedia has a [comparison of WebSocket implementations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_WebSocket_implementations).